# Universal Control stops working

Tags: ventura, universal-control

So I set up 2 MacBooks and Universal control works fine. But time passes, I turn on computers with the same setting and everything, but **Universal Control doesn't work till I restart both of them.**

What could be a problem? I do not change any settings.

MacOS Ventura 13.2.1 on both MacBook Pro 13", 2020 and MacBook Air M2, 2020

Comment: Does anything here work, it's kinda related. https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/441283/universal-control-stopped-working-12-4?rq=1